# Why are there two blocks? and why is the image not overlaying the block?

Tags: html, css

My issues are:
1) The "house" image isn't overlaying the block, instead it is sandwhiching itself inbetween..
2) There are two blocks, even though my code does not have two listed..

HTML doc:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="home_page_stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <a href="http://www.webapp.com/home">
            <img src="/Users/<<>>/Desktop/web_app/images/icons/home_icon_selected.png"/>
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS doc:

```
* {
    background-color: #EAE4C5;
}

 div {
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

What I end up getting is this:

[image]

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of the issue?

Comment: Based on the code you provided there is only one block: http://jsfiddle.net/t7a4h/

Comment: Press ctrl f5 to rid yourself of any cache that may still be there.

Comment: Weird.. by creating a new file it worked.. where do I do cntrl f5? on the browser or text editor?

also how to I get the image to overlay the block and not wedge itself in there?

Comment: The cache lies in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the home icon as a background to the div instead.

This can be done using the following CSS code. Update the file path to the image.

```
background-image: url('home_icon_selected.png');
```

In order to make the entire `div` clickable, you should wrap in inside the `a` tag as the following code:

```
<a href="http://www.webapp.com/home">
    <div>

    </div>
</a>
```

Consider adding a class identifier for your div, so that you can have multiple, different `div`s in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Add position: absolute; to your CSS then if you need to move the DIV you can use margins.